# $_GET value in PHP script called by AJAX has previous value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am developing a very simple shopping cart where each of the items (courts) in the store has a button next to it, a + if the item is not in the cart and an x if the item is in the cart.  When you click on the button I am submitting jQuery/AJAX/PHP to update the cart information and totals as well as change the button in the product list to an x, and vice versa.

Here is the product line in the store

```
<div id="courtline" class="courtline<?php echo $row_Courts['systemID']; ?>">
<a href="#" func="add" stateName="<?php echo $_SESSION['state'];?>" systemID="<?php echo $row_Courts['systemID'];?>" courtSystemID="<?php echo $row_Courts['courtSystem_SystemID']; ?>" userID="<?php echo $_SESSION['userid']; ?>" id="addCourtLinkADD" class="addCourtLinkADD" ><img src="assets/icons/add.gif"  /></a>
</div>
```

And here is my jQuery.  It makes 3 AJAX calls...

1. Update the database by adding or removing a product from the shopping cart...
2. Update the product list by changing the button to a + or x depending on whether the product is in the cart... it also changes the 'func' parameter to match the button.
3. update a totals div in the cart.

.

```
$(" #courtline" ).on( "click","a",function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var func = $(this).attr("func");
    var stateName =  $(this).attr("stateName");
    var courtID = $(this).attr("systemID");
    var userID = $(this).attr("userID");
    var courtSystemID = $(this).attr("courtSystemID");      
    var stateID = $(this).attr("systemID");

    // update the court list in the cart
    $.ajax({

        type: "GET",
        url: "http://subscribe.docketlaw.com/ajaxphp/modifyCourt.php",
        data: "user= " + userID + "& court= " + courtID + "& courtsystem= " + courtSystemID + "& func=" + func,
        timeout: 6000,
        success: function (data)
            {
                $(document).ready(
                    function() {
                        courtList = data;

                        $('div.cartcourtlist').html(courtList);
    // now update the Court Line                
        $.ajax({

            type: "GET",
            url: "http://subscribe.docketlaw.com/ajaxphp/refreshCourtLine.php",
            data: "user= " + userID + "& court= " + courtID + "& courtsystem= " + courtSystemID + "& statename=" + stateName + "& func=" + func,
            timeout: 6000,
            success: function (data)
                {
                    $(document).ready(
                        function() {

                            courtlinediv = data;  

                            $('div.courtline'+courtID).html(courtlinediv);      
            // now update the Totals                
            $.ajax({

                type: "GET",
                url: "http://subscribe.docketlaw.com/ajaxphp/refreshTotal.php",
                data: "user=" + userID + "& court=" + stateID + "& statename=" + stateName,
                timeout: 6000,
                success: function (data)
                    {
                        $(document).ready(
                            function() {
                                totaldiv = data; 

                                $('div.recurringtotal').html(totaldiv);             
                            }
                        );
                    }, 
                    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                        alert("Status refreshTotal: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
                    }   
            });                 
                        }
                    );
                }, 
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                    alert("Status refreshCourtLine: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
                }   
        });                 

                    }
                );
            }, 
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                alert("Status modifyCourt: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
            }   
    });
});
```

The relevant code in modifyCourt.php.  It updates the cart information by adding or removing a product from the cart.

```
if ($_GET['func'] == 'add') {

// insert the court into the cart
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO cart (sessionid, systemid, courttype) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($row_Result['sessionID'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_GET['court'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_GET['courtsystem'], "int"));

mysql_select_db($database_docketData, $docketData);
$Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $docketData) or die(mysql_error());

} else {

$deleteSQL = sprintf("DELETE FROM cart WHERE systemid=%s AND sessionid = %s",
                       GetSQLValueString($_GET['court'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($row_Result['sessionID'], "text"));

  mysql_select_db($database_docketData, $docketData);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($deleteSQL, $docketData) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Here is the relevant code from refreshCourtLine.php, which updates the button and the func attribute on the button.

`refreshCourtLine.php`

```
if ($_GET['func'] == 'add') {
    ?>  <a href="#" func="delete" stateName="<?php echo $_GET['statename'];?>" systemID="<?php echo $_GET['court'];?>" courtSystemID="<?php echo $_GET['courtsystem']; ?>" userID="<?php echo $_GET['user']; ?>" id="removeCourtLinkREMOVE" class="removeCourtLinkREMOVE" ><img src="assets/icons/delete.gif"  /></a>

     <?php } else {
    ?>
    <a href="#" func="add" stateName="<?php echo $_GET['statename'];?>" systemID="<?php echo $_GET['court'];?>" courtSystemID="<?php echo $_GET['courtsystem']; ?>" userID="<?php echo $_GET['user']; ?>" id="addCourtLinkADD" class="addCourtLinkADD" ><img src="assets/icons/add.gif"  /></a> 

    <?php }
```

So... when I click the add button, the product appears in the cart, the button changes to an x and the func attribute is changed to "delete", which is as expected.  However, if I click the new x button to remove that same product from the cart, it successfully removes the product from the cart, but it does not change the button back to a plus and does not change the func attribute.  Through investigation I've determined that when clicking the button that was generated through jQuery, the value for `$_GET['func']` in `modifyCourt.php` is correct (which explains why the product is correctly removed from the cart) but in `refreshCourtLine.php`, the value of `$_GET['func']` is the OLD value.

I've used alert throughout the jQuery and it always shows the value that is currently in the func attribute on the button, but once it goes into refreshCourtLine.php it goes back to the old value.

If I refresh the page, the buttons work as normal again.

I have a feeling it's an issue of scope, but I am confused as to why the first AJAX call to `modifyCourt.php` uses the new value of the func attribute but the second AJAX call to `refreshCourtLine.php` uses the old value.

sorry for being long-widnded and for the ugly code, but I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside jQuery's AJAX `success` event, you don't have to wrap the rest inside `$(document).ready()`, since that event has already been fired when the top most parent document was ready.. So maybe that's the issue.

From the partial code it's unclear if there might be a problem around the `$_GET['func']` retrieval in `refreshCourtLine.php`. You can try to 'vardump()' the `$_GET['func']` before the `if` to see what state it is in (is it set? what value? etc)

Furthermore, you use `courtline` as the ID of the div and a customized `coutline[ID]` as the class name. Why not switch those? So each item has a unique ID and a general class name. In this way, the items are easy to tell apart for the script.

So: `id="courtline" class="courtline<?php echo $row_Courts['systemID']; ?>"` should become `class="courtline" id="courtline<?php echo $row_Courts['systemID']; ?>"` and the jQuery selectors in your AJAX function should be changed as well. ( `$('#courtline' + courtID )` )

Also, use `data-` attributes instead of custom ones in your HTML. Browser can handle them better. And us jQuery's `.data('attributename')` to get the values.

Be aware that your `click` event binding refers to the anchor inside the DIV, so when you want to replace the link, use jQuery's `.replaceWith( '<a ...></a>' )` to replace it's HTML with the new link. (Because `.html( .. )` replaces the HTML inside the element, so not the A-tag itself.)

**Important**: please use PHP's MySQLi functions instead of the deprecated `mysql_query` etc. Have a look at the PHP documentation in that.
Also use `mysqli`'s prepared statements for safety :)

**Example** for a working front-end part: https://jsfiddle.net/PhilQ/v3ng3ejt/2/

Comment: thanks for the feedback!  I have verified that the `$_GET` array is populated and the `func` value is set to the old value.

Comment: i've swapped the `id` and `class` attributes on my `<div>` but am having a hard time getting the selector to trigger... the value of courtID isn't available to me until after the click.

Comment: You should set the `$(" #courtline" ).on( "click" ...` to `$(".courtline")`

Comment: so my selector now looks like `$(".courtline").on( "click","a",function( e ) {` and my `<div>` is defined as `<div class ="courtline" id="courtline<?php echo $row_Courts['systemID']; ?>">`,  but the selector is not firing because it's not matching the `div` `id` attribute to the selector.

Comment: You have several errors in your code. I made a simplified example for you at: https://jsfiddle.net/PhilQ/v3ng3ejt/2/  Have a look at the comments.

Comment: Also, use `data-attributes` instead of custom attributes in your HTML

Comment: you are right, there were a number of errors and i was over complicating the matter... i used your sample code to streamline my own code and it now works beautifully! i moved the `$( this ).replaceWith( newhtml );` at the beginning of the handler instead of inside the `success` clause of the first `ajax` call because i was getting an error that i think was because of the scope on `this`.  i switched to `data-attributes` as well.  thank you very much for your help, i have learned an awful lot from this!